# asmx service with silverlight VS2012

Tags: web-services, silverlight, visual-studio-2012, asmx

I'm trying to call an asmx service from a silverlight client but despite my best efforts I cannot get the generated proxy classes to be ObservableCollections, please help. I select ObservableCollection in the advanced configuration in the service reference, and I've tried updating the .svcmap file, but no success.

Any other ideas?

Comment: This must be Microsoft's way of irritating us out of using their awesome technology called Silverlight

Answer (score 0):

I don't have VS2012, but I am sure it should be same in VS2012 as of VS2010.
follow this steps

1) Add service reference (not web reference)
[image]

2) Go to Advanced Options

[image]

3) Choose Observale collection as option

[image]

4) You have your observale collection in proxy

[image]

Comment: As I said, I do select ObservableCollection in the advanced configuration but it does not work

Comment: oh.. I will try on VS2012 and will check out then.